# Fabric: use it without call fab app, in a python module?

Tags: python, fabric

I am learning about Fabric, since I need to operate on remote computer, and ssh via subprocess in shell is not really an option.

Now, I see everywhere that the common usage is to create a fabric.py file, where the commands are defined, and then call them via the fab app.

I would like to use Fabric from a Python function: I would like to import Fabric, set the env user and host, and then pass commands; but I can't find anywhere a tutorial that explain how you do so, without actually use the fab application or the fabric python file.

Is possible to use it as I would, or I am forced to use it trough the fab app and forced to create a separate file called fabric.py?

Answer (score 0):

The Fabric docs have a page on [library usage](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/usage/library.html).

Comment: Yes, I read that page, but it has no examples. There is a wealth of tutorials showing how to use it with the fab app, but for some reasons, not a single simple example about how to do the same as library.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for fabs [execute](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/tasks.html#fabric.tasks.execute) method. If this is not what you are looking for you should give us some pseudocode what you want to do.